# Can you search more than one database at a time using biopython

Tags: python, database, search, biopython, ncbi

My task is to use E-Utilties at NCBI to retrieve the number of papers submitted about the Crispr/Cas9 system for each of the last 10 years.  How would I go about searching multiple databases at once?  My code so far:

```
from Bio import Entrez


Entrez.email = "example@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2016/01/01, maxdate=2016/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2016 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2015/01/01, maxdate=2015/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2015 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2014/01/01, maxdate=2014/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2014 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2013/01/01, maxdate=2013/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2013 is: ", record["Count"]


handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2012/01/01, maxdate=2012/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2012 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2011/01/01, maxdate=2011/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2011 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2010/01/01, maxdate=2010/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2010 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2009/01/01, maxdate=2009/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2009 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2008/01/01, maxdate=2008/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2008 is: ", record["Count"]

handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr/Cas9 system", mindate=2007/01/01, maxdate=2007/01/01, datetype="pdat")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
record["Count"]
print "Number of papers in 2007 is: ", record["Count"]
```

Comment: which are databases are you interested in?

Comment: @Ashafix Well the problem says to use E-Utilties at NCBI to retrieve the number of papers submitted about the Crispr/Cas9 system, so I guess all of them that I can?

Comment: @Azaro In that case you only want one database: pubmed. I suspect that you want to do multiple concurrent requesting to pubmed.

Comment: Or one big search, and then parse the results to build a summary the results by year?

Answer (score 1):

As you may have recognized, your code is highly redundant, that's a typical case for a `for` loop:

```
from Bio import Entrez

years = range(2016, 2006, -1)  # Creates a list from 2016 to 2007

Entrez.email = "Example@mail.org"

for year in years:  # Go through the list 'years' and assign the value to the variable 'year'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db ="pubmed", term="Crispr Cas9",
                            mindate=year, maxdate=year)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    print "Number of papers in %d is %s" %(year, record["Count"])  # 'Old' string formatting
```

It is also unlikely that all papers that mention the CrispR/Cas9 system would use the exact phrase "Cripr/Cas9" and contain the word "system". You got more results by using the search term "Crispr Cas9".